# Get latest Apple pay transactions in Xamarin app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, applepay

After spending hours in reading documentation about Apple Pay and how to use it with Xamarin Forms I wonder if it is even possible to just simply get the latest transactions done with apple pay.

In the wallet app you have a list with the latest payments via apple pay. My goal is to get the latest payment and some information (amount, location) about this payment.

Is this possible in anyway? Probably someone can give me some hints or useful links. I DO NOT want to create a new transaction!

Comment: Sounds like something Apple wouldn't allow, given how private that information is.

Comment: You can't. That is private API that only Apple Wallet can access. Read the Apple Pay docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/